# Removing SWIG Generated Getter/Setters from Structure Java Class

Tags: swig

I'm using a javacode typemap to add some additional functions in place of the SWIG generated ones.  I would like to remove the SWIG generated default getter and setter for the `unsigned char mac[6];` (`public short[] getMac()` and `public void setMac(short[] value)`) of the `details_t_` structure.  I've tried to do using a `%ignore details_t_::setMac;` directive, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions as an appropriate technique to do this?

```
%module Test
%typemap(javacode) struct details_t_ %{
    public String getMacAddress() {
        return Test.getMacAddressAsString(this); //another API in Test.java
    }

%};

%rename (Details) details_t_;
typedef struct details_t_ {
    uint16_t                      code;
    char                          *name;
    sockaddr                      *saddr;
    uint32_t                      saddr_len;
    uint8_t                       flag;
    ios_boolean                   is_child;
    unsigned char                 mac[6];
} details_t;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of saying `%ignore` with the setter and getter, name the field itself directly, e.g.:

```
%module Test
%typemap(javacode) struct details_t_ %{
    public String getMacAddress() {
        return Test.getMacAddressAsString(this); //another API in Test.java
    }

%};

// Ignore field, not get/sets
%ignore details_t_::mac;
%rename (Details) details_t_;
typedef struct details_t_ {
    uint16_t                      code;
    char                          *name;
    sockaddr                      *saddr;
    uint32_t                      saddr_len;
    uint8_t                       flag;
    ios_boolean                   is_child;
    unsigned char                 mac[6];
} details_t;
```

If you want to make it immutable instead of hidden (i.e. only a getter, no setter generated) you can write:

```
%immutable details_t_::mac;
```

instead of `%ignore` in the previous example.

If you want to make the whole struct immutable you can do:

```
// Read only, i.e. only getters
%immutable;
%rename (Details) details_t_;
typedef struct details_t_ {
    uint16_t                      code;
    char                          *name;
    sockaddr                      *saddr;
    uint32_t                      saddr_len;
    uint8_t                       flag;
    ios_boolean                   is_child;
    unsigned char                 mac[6];
} details_t;

// Cancel the immutable directive
%mutable;
```

Comment: my goal is to provide a Java representation of Details.java that only has getters and no setters.  I basically want to make it an immutable object as the consuming methods will just call the getters to get the data. So I just want to hide the setter, is that possible?

Comment: @c12 - I added an example of making it immutable